# How do I get the REST Assured logs to be written in scenario.write()?

Tags: java, rest, cucumber, rest-assured, cucumber-java

I need to log the rest assured traffic - Doing that by using:  `when().post().then().log().all().extract().response();`
Now that puts the rest messages in std out, but I want those messages to be logged in cucumber report in the `AfterAll()` call via a `scenario.write()`.
How do I save the rest assured logs into a variable and pass that to `scenario.write()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [RequestLoggingFilter](http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.3.0/io/restassured/filter/log/RequestLoggingFilter.html) and [ResponseLoggingFilter](http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.3.0/io/restassured/filter/log/ResponseLoggingFilter.html) classes. Provide configured PrintStream to their constructor and add filters to request specification. It can look this way:

```
OutputStream outputStream = null; //use your OutputStream that will write where you need it

PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream, true);

RequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter = new RequestLoggingFilter(printStream);
ResponseLoggingFilter responseLoggingFilter = new ResponseLoggingFilter(printStream);

RestAssured.given()
    .filters(requestLoggingFilter, responseLoggingFilter)
    .when()
    .get("/api");
```

Or you can also implement [Filter](http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.3.0/io/restassured/filter/Filter.html) interface to use your own.
Here's an example for logging both request and response:

```
public class CustomLogFilter implements Filter {

  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomLogFilter.class);

  @Override
  public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec,
      FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
    Response response = ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
    StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    requestBuilder.append(requestSpec.getMethod());
    requestBuilder.append("\n");
    requestBuilder.append(requestSpec.getURI());
    requestBuilder.append("\n");
    requestBuilder.append("*************");
    log.info(requestBuilder.toString());  //Log your request where you need it
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    responseBuilder.append(response.getStatusLine());
    responseBuilder.append("\n");
    responseBuilder.append(response.getBody());
    log.info(responseBuilder.toString()); //Log your response where you need it
    return response;
  }
}
```

And then use it in RestAssured request:

```
Filter logFilter = new CustomLogFilter();
RestAssured.given()
    .filter(logFilter)
    .when()
    .get("/api");
```

Comment: OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream, true);
RequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter = new  RequestLoggingFilter(printStream);
ResponseLoggingFilter responseLoggingFilter = new ResponseLoggingFilter(printStream);
restAssuredResponseImpl = (RestAssuredResponseImpl) RestAssured.given().filters(requestLoggingFilter, responseLoggingFilter).log().all().
when().get().then().log().all().extract().response();
this.setResponseDataJson(restAssuredResponseImpl);
     String logDetail = printStream.toString();

Comment: That worked, now I need to find out how I can separate the request and the response parts. Rest logs the response right in the next line where the Request ends. Is there a way to insert like a line full of *********'s?

Comment: @HudBud108 You can implement your own filter and customize output there. I've updated the answer with example. Since I haven't worked with cucumber this example uses logger to show output

Comment: bhusak thanks and a question - Will the std out display as its logged into the logger in this case? I basically want both the log and stdout to look the same.

Comment: @HudBud108 Depends on what logging library you use it's possible to configure multiple appenders. As a result logs can go to sdtout, file, etc

Comment: I implemented as you indicated but now I am missing the output stream and inputstream as there is no request and response logging filter I am passing??

Answer (score 0):

We would need to convert first Response into String and then use this string reference in logs or scenario.write. I am trying to explain in below code -

```
    String responseString, placeid;
    private static Logger log =LogManager.getLogger(basics3.class.getName());
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        @Before
        public void getData() throws IOException
        {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//env.properties");
            prop.load(fis);
        }

        @Test
        public void AddandDeletePlace()
        {

            RestAssured.baseURI= prop.getProperty("HOST");
            Response res=given().

            queryParam("key",prop.getProperty("KEY")).
            body(payLoad.getPostData()).
            when().
            post(resources1.placePostData()).
            then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().
            body("status",equalTo("OK")).
            extract().response();

            responseString=res.asString();
            JsonPath js= new JsonPath(responseString);
            placeid=js.get("place_id");
        }

         @After
         public void setLogs(){
         log.info(responseString);          
         log.info(placeid);
         }
```

Hope this gives you some vision of printing REST Assured logs.

Comment: how do you log the request details? Not the one you put in, but the one that rest assured puts in the wire?